# About "nōn uidēmus manticae quod in tergō est"

Tags: idiom, case

In the famous latin expression

> *"nōn uidēmus manticae quod in tergō est".*

We see the word *manticae*. I always considered that this word must be the direct object of the sentence, however, if it was the case, one should expect the form *manticās*. Why does it happen? Why is it *manticae*?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is a partitive genitive, but the word order may be slightly misleading: the direct object of *videmus* is *quod in tergo est* and *manticae* modifies that, not the other way around.
If the object were *manticae* and  *quod in tergo est* were a subordinate clause depending on that, as might be the natural reading, the sentence would have to be "*non videmus manticam quae in tergo est*", with *manticam* in the accusative as you expected, and *quae* feminine because it refers to *mantica*.

Comment: Ah yes! It makes sense, a partitive was my second guess, but I totally forgot that it would be "quae" if "manticam" was the object! Thank you!